# How to actually use loop in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

I'm trying to make a web crawler. I use some loop inside. The loop run well for the first loop, but not to the second. I always get this message: "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred"

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


result = 
requests.get("http://desaku.bandungkab.go.id/desaonline/")
#This url is the main web, inside this web there are 270 links of 
#other website. I get into that 270 webs and open every article in 
#each 
web
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
links = soup.find_all('a')
urls = []
for link in links:
    if "www" in link.text:
        url = link.attrs['href']
        urls.append(url)


num1=len(urls)
b=0
while b<num1:
    result2 = requests.get(urls[b])
    src2 = result2.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src2, 'lxml')
    links2 = soup.find_all('a')
    urls2 = []
    for link in links2:
        if "selengkapnya" in link.text:
            url2 = link.attrs['href']
            urls2.append(url2)
    b+=1
#the code run well until this part. If i print this, it will result 
#url that take me directly to specific article

num=len(urls2)
i=0
while i<num:
    result2 = requests.get(urls2[i])
    src2 = result2.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src2, 'lxml')
    links2 = soup.find_all('a')
    artikel=[]
    isi = link.attrs['href']
    artikel.append(isi)
    print(artikel)
    i+=1
```

I expect to get all the link of article from the website and put them into a list called artikel=[]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are assigning to `urls2 = []` and to `artikel=[]` each loop iteration, effectively replacing the list. At the end of iteration you have empty array. You could use this code as a start:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = requests.get("http://desaku.bandungkab.go.id/desaonline/")
#This url is the main web, inside this web there are 270 links of
#other website. I get into that 270 webs and open every article in
#each web

src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

urls = []
urls2 = []

for link in soup.select('a[href]:contains(www)'):
    urls.append(link['href'])

print('Urls:')
for url in urls:
    print('Downloading {}'.format(url))
    result2 = requests.get(url)
    src2 = result2.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src2, 'lxml')
    for link in soup.select('a[href]:contains(selengkapnya)'):
        print('\tFound link {}'.format(link['href']))
        urls2.append(link['href'])

print('Articles:')
articles = []
for url2 in urls2:
    print('Downloading {}'.format(url2))
    result2 = requests.get(url2)
    src2 = result2.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src2, 'lxml')
    for link in soup.find_all('a[href]'):
        articles.append(link['href'])

print(articles)
```

Prints:

```
Urls:
Downloading http://www.ancolmekar.desa.id
    Found link http://www.ancolmekar.desa.id/first/artikel/423
    Found link http://www.ancolmekar.desa.id/first/artikel/421
    Found link http://www.ancolmekar.desa.id/first/artikel/420
    Found link http://www.ancolmekar.desa.id/first/artikel/419
    Found link http://www.ancolmekar.desa.id/first/artikel/414
    Found link http://www.ancolmekar.desa.id/first/artikel/413
    Found link http://www.ancolmekar.desa.id/first/artikel/412
    Found link http://www.ancolmekar.desa.id/first/artikel/410
    Found link http://www.ancolmekar.desa.id/first/artikel/410
    Found link http://www.ancolmekar.desa.id/first/artikel/100
Downloading http://www.arjasari.desa.id
    Found link http://www.arjasari.desa.id/first/artikel/180
    Found link http://www.arjasari.desa.id/first/artikel/190

...and so on.
```

Comment: I got this message after running the code:
/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/acer/PycharmProjects/bs1/example8.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/acer/PycharmProjects/bs1/example8.py", line 15, in <module>
    for link in soup.select('a[href]:contains(www)'):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1451, in select
    'Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.')
NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.

Comment: I see, i haven't update my bs4 thank you so much, i have been working on this for a week. But if i wan to get the content of the articles i just need to change the last code, is that right?

Comment: @SaepulAnwar Make sure you don't set `urls` and `urls2` to [] each iteration.